# Logout from all apps in .net core 3.1

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

When i logout from one app, I should be logged out from other apps as well if i am logged-in. I am going through lots of URL but didn't get that. How can i achieve this in .net core 3.1 with Identity Server?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer supports the [front-channel specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html) for server-side clients (e.g. MVC), the [back-channel specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) for server-side clients, and the [session management specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) for browser-based JavaScript clients (e.g. SPA, React, Angular, etc.). Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html?highlight=back%20channel#notifying-clients-that-the-user-has-signed-out).

Sample clients: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Clients/old/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridBackChannel

Edit:
To implement front channel logout you need to make two change:

1. On client app add the front-channel action like this:

```
[Route("frontchannellogout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FrontChannelLogout(string sid)
      {
          if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
              var currentSid = User.FindFirst("sid")?.Value ?? "";
              if (string.Equals(currentSid, sid, StringComparison.Ordinal))
              {
                  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
              }
          }
 
          return NoContent();
      }
```

2. On client config within IdentityServer

```
new Client
               {       
                    ...

                    FrontChannelLogoutUri= "http://localhost:5002/frontchannellogout"

                    ...
               },
```

Comment: for back channel, use https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridBackChannel @Jitendra

Comment: any luck? @Jitendra

Comment: I am trying it by front-channel.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do it by front-channel, or both front and back channel works same? @nahidf

Comment: I have client details in a method named as **public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()** in **Config.cs** file and this method will return client list. How and where i can use this or it will be called automatically? @nahidf

Comment: and i am trying in MVC .net core 3.1. And it's showing error while i am returning  return NoContent();

Comment: Find you client on ‘GetClients()‘ method and add the set ‘ FrontChannelLogoutUri ’ for it - you can find the client using client Id matching the mvc

Comment: For the logout action on mvc, what I have is just sample code you can adjust as you wish - for no content make sure you have the namespace listed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.nocontent?view=aspnetcore-3.1